# How to get user's location accuracy in meters?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, geolocation, location

I want to get user's location accuracy (circle's radius) in meters.

I have been searching about a day but I couldn't find any solution about this problem.

```
Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best);

//This is gives from 0-100m accuracy on Android, instead of best or high, I want to be able to pass the accuracy in meters.
```

How to precise the accuracy in meters?

Comment: Are you using a package?

Comment: Yes I'm using geolocator package

Comment: I don't know if this helps but I think the location package can do what you need: https://pub.dev/packages/location

Comment: Thanks for response. As far as I know location package doesn't have a parameter that gives location accuracy in meters.

Comment: This issue is closed now as not planned see: https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator/issues/1148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the documentation thoroughly before asking on SO.

Both the [`geolocator`](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) and [`location`](https://pub.dev/packages/location) packages provide this ability.

The `geolocator` package has an [`accuracy`](https://pub.dev/documentation/geolocator_platform_interface/latest/geolocator_platform_interface/Position/accuracy.html) property on the `Position` object it uses.

```dart
final geo = Geolocator();
final location = await geo.getCurrentPosition();
print(location.accuracy);
```

The `location` package has an [`accuracy`](https://pub.dev/documentation/location_platform_interface/latest/location_platform_interface/LocationData/accuracy.html) property on the `LocationData` object it uses.

```dart
final loc = Location();
final locData = await loc.getLocation();
print(locData.accuracy);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would sugget that you read the documentation

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation);
```

View [this](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator#location-accuracy) table

also don't forget to add these to your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I have read the documentation and also using getCurrentPosition function with desiredAccuracy parameter but the point of question is that how to get accuracy in meters like (current position accuracy is 50 meters)

Comment: well from the docs and that table, the best thing that it can offer is a range from 0-100 from android and 0 meters from ios, and since this package is flutter fav, so I think you won't get any better